# Spike in MySQL connections causing high CPU usage

Tags: mysql

I am trying to solve a performance problem for my client. They seem to have very high sudden connection spike during specific periods (e.g from 100-998), CPU shoots high during that period as well (e.g from 30-90%).

```
query_cache size is 16MB

max_connections 2486
```

Any reason why this could be happening?

Comment: Have you monitored to see what queries the server is receiving during the spike? Maybe there is a regular process that runs queries during that time.

Comment: If it is during specific (regular) periods it may be some sort of (somewhat odd) non local machine backing procedure taking all the contents data and saving it in a reserve SQL database.